# Change default behavior of callout blocks in Quarto

Tags: r-markdown, quarto

In Quarto, I'd like to change the default behavior of a single [callout block](https://quarto.org/docs/authoring/callouts.html) type so that it will

1. always automatically have the same [caption](https://quarto.org/docs/authoring/callouts.html#markdown-syntax) (*e.g.* "Additional Resources")
2. always be [folded](https://quarto.org/docs/authoring/callouts.html#collapse) (`collapse="true"`)

Let's say I want this for the `tip` callout block type while the others (`note`, `warning`, `caution`, and `important`) should not be affected.

In other words, I want the behavior/output of this:

```r
:::{.callout-tip collapse="true"}
## Additional Resources

-   Resource 1

-   Resource 2
:::
```

by only having to write this:

```r
:::{.callout-tip}
-   Resource 1

-   Resource 2
:::
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:**

I have actually converted the following lua filter into a quarto filter extension [`collapse-callout`](https://github.com/shafayetShafee/collapse-callout), which allows specifying default options for specific callout blocks more easily. See the github readme for detailed instructions on installation and usage.

---

As @stefan mentioned, you can use pandoc Lua filter to do this more neatly.

**quarto_doc.qmd**

```
---
title: "Callout Tip"
format: html
filters: 
  - custom-callout.lua
---

## Resources

:::{.custom-callout-tip}
-   Resource 1

-   Resource 2
:::


## More Resources

:::{.custom-callout-tip}
-   Resource 3

-   Resource 4
:::
```

**custom-callout.lua**

```
local h2 = pandoc.Header(2, "Additional Resources")

function Div(el)
  if quarto.doc.isFormat("html") then
    if el.classes:includes('custom-callout-tip') then
      local content = el.content
      table.insert(content, 1, h2)
      return pandoc.Div(
        content,
        {class="callout-tip", collapse='true'}
      )
    end
  end
end
```

---

[image: custom callout tip blocks]

---

Just make sure that `quarto_doc.qmd` and `custom-callout.lua` files are in the same directory (i.e. folder).

Comment: Check the edited answer.  I think it's better to use a custom class name `.custom-callout-tip` rather than using `.callout-tip` to do this.

Comment: Very nice. Good job. Any hints on good references using lua with quarto?

Comment: Quarto doc has [a section](https://quarto.org/docs/extensions/lua.html#learning-lua) on this. but TBH, I myself am in the learning process and trying to find documentation with lots of examples or a book regarding this. Specifically, I have skimmed over the codes in [`quarto-ext`s](https://github.com/quarto-ext) to answer this question.

Comment: Thx Shafee. I wrote myself some small lua filters for my company Rmd template. And that was too, more of a trial and error approach as I wasn't able to find any good references.

Comment: Same. I am also going through the trial and error approach here :-)

Comment: Fantastic! I've used this now (adding the `custom-callout.lua` file to the main project folder and `filters:  - custom-callout.lua` to my website's main `_quarto.yaml`.

Comment: @PaulSchmidt, and @stefan, I am very excited to let you guys to know about [`callout-collapse`](https://github.com/shafayetShafee/collapse-callout) :D

Comment: Sorry, maybe I've overlooked something but this solution suddenly does not work anymore for me. Was there a breaking change in an update or is it just me and you cant reproduce it.

Comment: @PaulSchmidt, Have you tried the filter [`callout-collapse`](https://github.com/shafayetShafee/collapse-callout)? If so, and if the problem still persists please file an issue with reprex in the filter repository.

Answer (score 3):

After a look at the docs and based on my experience with customizing Rmarkdown I would guess that this requires to create a custom template and/or the use of pandoc Lua filters.

A more lightweight approach I used in the past would be to use a small custom function to add the code for your custom callout block to your Rmd or Qmd. One drawback is that this requires a code chunk. However, to make your life a bit easier you could e.g. create a RStudio snippet to add a code chunk template to your document.

````
---
title: "Custom Callout"
format: html
---

```{r}
my_call_out <- function(...) {
  cat(":::{.callout-tip collapse='true'}\n")
  cat("## Additional Resources\n")
  cat(paste0("- ", ..., collapse = "\n\n"))
  cat("\n:::\n")
}
```

```{r results="asis"}
my_call_out(paste("Resource", 1:2))
```

Blah blah

```{r results="asis"}
my_call_out("Resource 3", "Resource 4")
```

Blah blah
````

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This works perfectly fine for me and I find it pretty ingenious. One of the annoying parts for me was actually that the caption would show up in RStudio's document outline and this is fixed here, too.

Answer (score 0):

Bit late to the party, but still gonna put it out there:
You can specify the title for a block-type in the file `_quarto.yml`.

```
callout-tip-title: "Resources"
```

Sadly, there isn't an option to collapse callout-blocks by default.
You can find more useful yaml-defaults [here](https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/blob/main/src/resources/language/_language.yml).
For example, I tend to remove the callout-icons with `callout-icon: false`.